# Does WP Have a Function To Generate .htaccess RewriteCond?

Tags: plugin-development, htaccess, apache, rewrite-rules

I know that I can edit .htaccess manually and add a RewriteCond statement inside, but I need to build a plugin that does this the proper way by using WP rewrites which then get pushed into .htaccess with flush_rewrite_rules(). I need RewriteCond in this case.

Does WP have some obscure function that lets me push a RewriteCond statement into the .htaccess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short yes...

#### 'External' Rewrite Rules

If in `add_rewrite_rule` the rule is isn't directed to `index.php` then the rule is treated as an 'external' rule (i.e. not to be processed by WordPress' internal handing of rewrites) and instead written to the `.htaccess` file. I.e. if:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','somethingelse.php?p=12&food=$1 &variety=$2','top');
```

is used instead of

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
```

Then the rule is recognised as a non (internal) WordPress rule and is added the .htaccess file rather than dealt with internally. **Note** for 'external' rules - you use `$1` instead of `$matches[1]`;

#### Adding custom rules to .htaccess

When rewrite rules are flushed, the `.htacess` file is written to. There is a hook which filters what is actually written. `mod_rewrite_rules`

```
function wpse50631_htaccess( $rules ){
   //Append or preppend extra rules.
   return $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'wpse50631_htaccess');
```

The [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) has this to say:

> `mod_rewrite_rules()` is the function that takes the array generated by rewrite_rules() and actually turns it into a set of rewrite rules for the `.htaccess` file. This function also has a filter, `mod_rewrite_rules`, which will pass functions the string of all the rules to be written out to `.htaccess`, including the `<IfModule>` surrounding section. (Note: you may also see plugins using the rewrite_rules hook, but this is deprecated).

Comment: Aha! The main thing is that last section you have in vanilla here. This is where I can edit the string that gets written and this is where I can add RewriteCond.

Comment: @Volomike It's wise to note that not every wordpress install allows wordpress to directly modify the .htaccess, so don't bank on being able to...at the very least throw a warning and some instructions to do it manually if it can't be done programatically.